# overlapping each other when performing rotate3d animation on one of them

Tags: css

I have a few divs in a container:

```
<div class="waves-container" id="waves_container">
    <div class="wave-wrapper wave-back">
        <img src="static/images/waves/sea_back.png" class="wave-top" />
        <div class="wave-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wave-wrapper wave-front">
        <img src="static/images/waves/sea-front.png" class="wave-top" />
        <div class="wave-bottom" id="wave_bottom_front">Some additional divs are created here dynamically with JS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="play-button" id="play_button">
        <img src="static/images/ccs_shake_waves/play.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Their CSS:

```
.waves-container {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
position: absolute;
bottom: -35%;
-webkit-transition: bottom 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.wave-wrapper {
width: 105%;
height: 130%;
position: absolute;
left: -5%;
}

.wave-top {
width:100%;
height: auto;
position:relative;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
float: left;
}

.wave-bottom {
width: 100%;
height: 130%;
position: relative;
clear:both;
float: left;
background-color: #fd51df;
}

.wave-back {
-webkit-animation: wave 3s 1s infinite linear;
top: 1.5%;
}

.wave-front {
top: -12%;
-webkit-animation: wave 3s infinite linear;
}

.play-button {
width: 70%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0, 0);
z-index:1;
display: none;
}
```

With JS on a certain event I'm attaching an animation class to `#play_button`:

```
.pop-play {
-webkit-animation: flipInY 1s 1 forwards ease-out, play 3s 1s infinite linear;
}
```

In `flipInY` I'm animating this div on Y axis:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg) translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg) scale(1.05, 1) translateY(-50%);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) scale(1.1, 1) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

In Android I see it just fine. However in iOS the `play_button` div overlaps with underlying div when it flips on Y axis, so every time I see 50% of the image, the rest of that div is "under" another div.

I tried to add `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to every underlying div, tried to change z-indexes, tried to combine it, tried to use

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

on the `waves-container` div and all the child divs, but they're still overlapping, until the flipping animation finishes and the other begins.

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a working example that clearly shows the problem you are experiencing? You can use a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to create a simple example.

Comment: Or you could just use the code snippet tool built right into Stack Overflow.

Comment: @misterManSam Well, it's kinda hard to replicate it, but I tried to make it as close as possible to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/e791mrnc/ See the green div, that's the one that's supposed to be animated. I test it in desktop Chrome browser and it works fine. The exact same code behaved differently in webkit in iOS (when the green div makes the flipping animation I only see 50% of it, it's like the rest of it is going behind the underlying div).

Comment: @Nit Oops, not familiar with that tool, how do I use it?